# c++ - std::string and move_iterator

Tags: c++, string, c++11, iterator, move-semantics

I was writing a tokenizer that would split a `string` and put each of the fields inside a `vector`. My idea was to use `string::find` repeatedly. Instead of using a temporary `string` object, I used `move_iterator`s, as I supposed the original string would see its characters stolen as the algorithm processed it. But it didn't happen.

This is an example code that demonstrates what I'm talking about:

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void
print_strings
    ( const vector<string> & v )
{
    unsigned int i = 1;
    for ( const auto & s : v )
        cout << "#" << i++ << "\t: \"" << s << "\"" << endl;
    return;
}

int
main
    ( void )
{
    string base( "hello, this is an example string, I like icescreams" );

    /* Vector to populate with strings */
    vector<string> v;

    /* 1: a copy of 'base' */
    v.emplace_back( base );
    /* 2: a copy of 'base' using iterators */
    v.emplace_back( base.begin() , base.end() );
    /* 3: a string that I think _should_ move from 'base' */
    v.emplace_back( make_move_iterator(base.begin()) , make_move_iterator(base.end()) );

    /* Print the strings twice so that we
     * can see if something has changed. */
    print_strings( v );
    print_strings( v );

    return 0;
}
```

When compiled with `g++ -std=c++11 -Wall -Wextra -Werror -O2`, it shows no warnings.

My guessings are that `string`'s constructors, in its *range* version, always copies from the specified range. As I'm not sure, I'd like to be sure and, of course, to see any workarounds you had used.

Best regards,
Kalrish

Comment: Moving from a `char` it the same as copying from it. You also never print `base` to see if it changed.

Comment: @jrok Indeed, I forgot to do that. Now that I've tried it, I can say `base` is not modified.

Comment: There is no single rvalue in that sample

Comment: What do you think moving a `char` from a `std::string` should do?  This is an X/Y problem: your solution (moving `char` from a `std::string`) is not your problem -- your problem is something else, and you thought "moving `char` will solve it, wait, it does not work".  Describe your *concrete* problem, describe what is supposed to happen to some data, and give examples of what state the data is in before and after the code that you don't know how to write.  Maybe even give your alternative implementation that you want to avoid.

Answer (score 0):

Iterators don't know anything about the container.

A `move_iterator` can't magically move from the string. It can't only move from its underlying element, that's a single `char` and moving from a char is the same as copying it. You need to use `std::move(base)`.

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void
print_strings
    ( const vector<string> & v )
{
    unsigned int i = 1;
    for ( const auto & s : v )
        cout << "#" << i++ << "\t: \"" << s << "\"" << endl;
    return;
}

int
main
    ( void )
{
    string base( "hello, this is an example string, I like icescreams" );

    /* Vector to populate with strings */
    vector<string> v;

    /* 1: a copy of 'base' */
    v.emplace_back( base );
    /* 2: a copy of 'base' using iterators */
    v.emplace_back( base.begin() , base.end() );
    /* 3: a string that I think _should_ move from 'base' */

    std::cout << base << '\n'; // base is still untouched here

    v.emplace_back( std::move(base) ); // now it'll be moved from

    print_strings( v );
    std::cout << "base: " << base << "/base\n"; // base is empty
    return 0;
}
```

See it live [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=6ef78fd97bd2148e901009f359cf7931-d453f8cdb05876c21842cb19504c959f).

Comment: The problem is that I'd like to move from a range, not the entire string.

Comment: You already did that, conceptualy, with `move_iterator`s. It's just that you dont' really gain much with `std::string`. What (I think) you'd want is to "steal" a part of string's buffer. That can't be done, I'm afraid.

Comment: If, as you state, is not possible, I guess this question makes no sense. I'll go with temporaries. Thank you for your help!